# Eclipse is not applying Save Actions when I format a whole (java) package

Tags: eclipse, formatting

I have configured Eclipse to format source code and trim trailing spaces on all lines on saving a file. This works as expected when I edit a source file and save it.

However these save actions are not executed when I right click on a package and execute the `Source > Format` command. The files *do* get saved after formatting but the trailing spaces are not removed. A quick experiment revealed that none of the actions defined under "Save Actions" are executed when a whole package is formatted.

How can I fix this?

I am using Eclipse Version 3.6.2 (Build id: M20110210-1200) on 64 bit Ubuntu Lucid.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `Source -> Clean Up...` command instead of `Format` for batch normalization, but you will still need to manually configure it.

Comment: Clean up doesn't remove trailing spaces that were inserted by formatting action. See https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=49619 and https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=270745